# Adding two vectors in Python 3 using the __add__ method

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, vector

I want to add two vectors with n dimensions using the `__add__` method. The elements of the 2 vectors will be input by the user. I don't understand how to define the vector as a single object.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO.  When asking a question, you need to provide an example of an attempt or something you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

In order to define a couple of vector in python and add them, you just need to do:

```
import numpy as np

v1 = np.array([3,2,1])
v2 = np.array([5,6,2])

sum_vector = v1 + v2
```

This code will add the 3D-vectors (3,2,1) and (5,6,2)

Good luck!